# Add a list under an <li> when clicking that <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a nested list.  When clicking on an `<li>` an unordered list should be appended to the `<li>` that was clicked on.

After clicking the first `<li>` my code fails and does not append lists to the newly inserted `<li>`.  I would like add the unordered list to the any `<li>` that is in the list.

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/s9204kyh/

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    var html = '<ul><li>Click to add a nested list item</li></ul>';

    $(this).append(html);
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="click">Click to add a nested list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you actually already know the answer to this question, so I'm going to let you answer it yourself: if I bind an event listener to an element, and that element builds something else, does that newly built element get an event listener without me saying so?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No, I don't think it does get the event listener.  I had tried making the `click` event bubble up to the div.container element.  But that was adding some odd behavior by appending lists to every <li>

Comment: I had hoped you would answer with "ohhh, I'm not giving the newly built element its own onclick handler, haha".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just updated the fiddle to do that!  Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. I'm not sure if it's exactly what you need.

You can delegate the event handling to the `.container`, and check some criteria to see if the `<li>` is appropriate for appending a new list. In my example, a new list is only appended if the clicked `<li>` does not already container a `<ul>` tag.

JS (jQuery):

```
var html = '<ul><li>Click to add a nested list item</li></ul>';

$('.container').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    $(e.target).filter(':not(:has(ul))').append(html);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/1tk715wd/).

Comment: Thank you!  I had forgotten what Mike'Pomax'Kamermans said above, and waht you showed.  I needed to target the element that triggered the event.  I updated the fiddle to show what I was trying to do.  I'm not doing the filtering because I'd like to continue to appened to the parent <li>'s if clicked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I need a help for you.

JS with JQuery

```
var addNestedListItem = function(ev) {
    var html = '<ul><li>Click to add a nested list item</li></ul>';
    $(ev.target).parent().append(html);
    $('li').off('click').on('click', addNestedListItem);
};
$('li').on('click', addNestedListItem);
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="click">Click to add a nested list item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vfb8yare/

Comment: Why the additional `<span>`?

Comment: But this adds additional event handlers to already existing `<span>`s. In your fiddle, clicking the second time adds 2 lists, then 3 the third time, and so on.

Comment: I have a mistake. sorry. I find my mistake and delete comment. I don't see additional comment. This is sorry too. :(

Comment: I have fixed my bugs in answer. Thanks @flowstoneknight your advices are helpful.

Comment: No worries about the comments. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mike'Pomax'Kamermans for pointing to the flaw in my original code.

Here is the JavaScript I was looking for:

```
$('li').on('click', function(e) {
    var html = '<ul><li>Click to add a nested list item</li></ul>';

    $(e.target).append(html);
});
```